# Disable line wrapping in .NET ListView

Tags: c#, .net, listview

Can anyone help with this simple question.

I have a c# ListView. It's the only control on the form. The View property is set to details. When I resize the form I programmatically resize the ListView to fill the whole form.

Problem is, when the form width gets too small to show the lines of text in the ListView it wraps each onto more lines of text - I can just see the top of the characters of the second line.

Thing is, I would rather only have one line per item and the user would have to use the mouse to horizontally scroll the "too long" items - just like in an edit box when the text is too long.

Thanks for any help,
Mitch.

Comment: There is no point in letting the user resize the window so small that it becomes unusable.   Not that he ever would but you are complaining about it anyway.  Easy peasy, simply set the form's MinimumSize property to the smallest reasonable value.

Comment: You could throw your listview into a panel and set the Scroll Bars property and then set the size of the panel to what you feel is best.